# Neither the Windows button nor the mouse work on my Windows 10 machine. How do I access settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Neither the Windows button nor the mouse work on my Windows 10 OS. The other keys seem to work. How do I access settings or the command prompt so that I can try to see if it's a driver issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do CTRL+SHIFT+ESCAPE to open Task Manager, then do ALT+F to select and open the File context menu. Press ENTER, then type `cmd` or `cmd.exe` in the Run prompt. Then you can do Tab+Space to check the `Create this task with administrative privilege` box (if applicable), then simply press ENTER to open the command prompt.